# In (Kendo Grid Angular 2) filter menu, how to hide the extra filter, and the operator dropdown

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

In Kendo UI for Angular 2:

1- How can I hide the extra filter options (the filter at the bottom in the picture).

2- For the first (remaining) filter: how to set a default operation and then hide the operations dropdown?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide the extra filter by setting `[extra]="false"` at the `kendo-grid-date-filter-menu` component. ([API Reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/DateFilterMenuComponent/#toc-extra))

The default operator can be set by utilizing the `operator` input.

**Example:**

```
<kendo-grid-column field="myDate" title="Title">
    <ng-template kendoGridFilterMenuTemplate
        let-filter let-column="column" let-filterService="filterService"> 

        <kendo-grid-date-filter-menu
          [column]="column" [filter]="filter" [filterService]="filterService"
          [extra]="false"
          operator="eq"
        >
        </kendo-grid-date-filter-menu>

    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

When it comes to hiding the operators-dropdown, there is no configuration-option right now for the filter-menu.
For the row-filter approach this is possible by setting `[showOperators]="false"`.

You can get around this limitation by either hiding it via css (but this still would be a workaround), or by implementing a custom filter that fits your requirements. ([Documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/filtering/reusable-filter/))

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to have those configs for all the columns in the grid at once? other than customizing the template for each column?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: The [extra]="false" was life saving!!! You sir are a God among men!

Answer (score 0):

A css workaround can be like this:

```
kendo-grid-filter-menu-container {
    kendo-dropdownlist.k-filter-and {
        display: none !important;
    }

    kendo-grid-string-filter-menu-input,
    kendo-grid-date-filter-menu-input  {
        &:nth-child(1) {
            kendo-grid-filter-menu-input-wrapper {
                kendo-dropdownlist:nth-child(1) {
                    display: none !important;
                }
            }
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
            display: none !important;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm still in need for better Kendo configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the default filter operator](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/filtering/built-in-template/#toc-setting-the-default-filter-operator) as reference.

The following example demonstrates how to configure a string filter and select the "contains" operator as default, also you can specify the active filter operators with their order using this tag: **`<kendo-filter-(operatorName)-operator>`**.

```html
<ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
    <kendo-grid-string-filter-cell [column]="column" [filter]="filter" operator="contains">
        <kendo-filter-contains-operator></kendo-filter-contains-operator>
        <kendo-filter-eq-operator></kendo-filter-eq-operator>
    </kendo-grid-string-filter-cell>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who use this workaround as @Hashem explained dont forget to add **kendo-grid-numeric-filter-menu-input**

```
kendo-grid-filter-menu-container {
  kendo-dropdownlist.k-filter-and {
      display: none !important;
  }

  kendo-grid-numeric-filter-menu-input,
  kendo-grid-string-filter-menu-input,
  kendo-grid-date-filter-menu-input  {
      &:nth-child(1) {
          kendo-grid-filter-menu-input-wrapper {
              kendo-dropdownlist:nth-child(1) {
                  display: none !important;
              }
          }
      }
      &:nth-child(3) {
          display: none !important;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<kendo-grid-column field="OrderDate" title="Order Date">
    <ng-template kendoGridFilterCellTemplate let-filter let-column="column">
        <kendo-grid-date-filter-cell [showOperators]="false" [column]="column" [filter]="filter">
        </kendo-grid-date-filter-cell>
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

---

```
[showOperators]="false" it work for me. Hide other operators
```

source Link : [DateFilterCellComponent](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/DateFilterCellComponent/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your answer with an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)

Comment: Thanks @Xasanali, please note that your answer works only with "Filter row", but not for "Menu filter"